# Laravel send email with multiple senders

Tags: laravel, email, gmail

I have a Laravel application that send two different kind of emails from different senders. One for the users and other one for the admins.

The emails for the admins works fine, i'm using smtp gmail.

How can I send the other type of emails using different sender? Thank you.

Comment: you can just set one email driver in same time

Comment: So can you suggest me a solution for my problem?

Comment: why you want to send emails from different email sender?

Comment: Because I have emails for the Admin (ex: admin@email.com) and another emails for users from (ex: info@email.com)

Comment: I this the best way is to use swift_mailer

Comment: you dont need 2 different mail sender you can set a driver for both emails , user asd admin, and just change From email for them , what is your laravel version?

Comment: @atf.sgf my laravel version is 5.6

Comment: ok, just set different from address in mailable class like this link:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#configuring-the-sender

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `from()` function in the mailable or the facade (if Mailables aren't in your version of Laravel):

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#configuring-the-sender